# Picking up Ctrl/Shift+Click with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, mouseevent

I am working on using event.ctrlKey and event.shiftKey in my onClick event to allow for multiple selections in a menu. To keep things simple, I replaced the action to be taken in the code here with some console logs. With the code below, if I put in breakpoints and inspect the event mid-execution after clicking while holding shift or control, I am unable to find the ctrl/shift booleans on the event and the code determines the first two parts of the logic to be false and prints "click".

Method

```
handleOnClick = (e, id) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('control ')
  } else if (e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift ')
  } else {
    console.log('click ')
  }
}
```

Execution

```
<ListItem
 key={q}
 onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(event, q.get('_id'))}
>
```

I was noticing in my research that it seems the *KeyboardEvent* (not MouseEvent) is really the one that has the boolean properties for shiftKey and ctrlKey, but all of the examples I have found don't seem to address this differentiation.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can get my code to hit the appropriate part of the logic for handleOnClick when the shift or control keys are held during the click? Right now, my console prints "click", no matter what combination of clicks and keystrokes (or lack thereof) I employ....

Comment: Someone might have a cleaner solution, but have you tried setting a global boolean variable to true when the shift or ctrl key is pressed during the onKeyDown event (and respectively setting it to false onKeyUp) and then checking against that global variable in the onClick event?

Comment: I have not! Thank you :) I'll try that, at least to get me functioning, if only in the intereum.... You are amazing!